# My LSTM text classification model seems not learn anything in early epochs

Tags: recurrent-neural-networks, long-short-term-memory, text-classification

I am trying to use LSTM to do text classification and monitor the training process with tensorboard. But it seems that this model doesn't learn anything in early epochs. Is it normal for LSTM networks?

Here is the definition of model:

```
class RNN(nn.Module):
    """
        RNN model for text classification
    """
    def __init__(self, vocab_size, num_class, emb_dim, emb_droprate, rnn_cell_hidden, rnn_cell_type, birnn, num_layers, rnn_droprate, sequence_len):
        super().__init__()
        self.vocab_size = vocab_size                # vocab size
        self.emb_dim = emb_dim                      # embedding dimension
        self.emb_droprate = emb_droprate            # embedding droprate
        self.num_class = num_class                  # classes
        self.rnn_cell_hidden = rnn_cell_hidden      # hidden layer size
        self.rnn_cell_type = rnn_cell_type          # rnn cell type
        self.birnn = birnn                          # wheather use bidirectional rnn
        self.num_layers = num_layers                # number of rnn layers
        self.rnn_droprate = rnn_droprate            # rnn dropout rate before fc
        self.sequence_len = sequence_len            # fix sequence length, so we dont need loop
        pass

    def build(self):
        self.embedding = nn.Embedding(self.vocab_size, self.emb_dim)
        self.emb_dropout = nn.Dropout(self.emb_droprate)
        if self.rnn_cell_type == "LSTM":
            self.rnn = nn.LSTM(input_size=self.emb_dim, hidden_size=self.rnn_cell_hidden, num_layers=self.num_layers, bidirectional=self.birnn, batch_first=True)
        elif self.rnn_cell_type == "GRU":
            self.rnn = nn.GRU(input_size=self.emb_dim, hidden_size=self.rnn_cell_hidden, num_layers=self.num_layers, bidirectional=self.birnn, batch_first=True)
        else:
            self.rnn = None
            print("unsupported rnn cell type, valid is [LSTM, GRU]")
        if self.birnn:
            self.fc = nn.Linear(2 * self.rnn_cell_hidden, self.num_class)
        else:
            self.fc = nn.Linear(self.rnn_cell_hidden, self.num_class)

        self.rnn_dropout = nn.Dropout(self.rnn_droprate)

    def forward(self, input_):
        batch_size = input_.shape[0]

        x = self.embedding(input_)
        x = self.emb_dropout(x)

        if self.rnn_cell_type == "LSTM":
            if self.birnn:
                h_0 = torch.zeros(self.num_layers * 2, batch_size, self.rnn_cell_hidden, requires_grad=True).to(device)
                c_0 = torch.zeros(self.num_layers * 2, batch_size, self.rnn_cell_hidden, requires_grad=True).to(device)
            else:
                h_0 = torch.zeros(self.num_layers, batch_size, self.rnn_cell_hidden, requires_grad=True).to(device)
                c_0 = torch.zeros(self.num_layers, batch_size, self.rnn_cell_hidden, requires_grad=True).to(device)
            output, (h_n, c_n) = self.rnn(x, (h_0, c_0))
        elif self.rnn_cell_type == "GRU":
            if self.birnn:
                h_0 = torch.zeros(self.num_layers * 2, batch_size, self.rnn_cell_hidden, requires_grad=True).to(device)
            else:
                h_0 = torch.zeros(self.num_layers, batch_size, self.rnn_cell_hidden, requires_grad=True).to(device)
            output, h_n = self.rnn(x, h_0)

        if self.birnn:
            x = h_n.view(self.num_layers, 2, batch_size, self.rnn_cell_hidden)
            x = torch.cat((x[-1, 0, : , : ], x[-1, 1, : , : ]), dim = 1)
        else:
            x = h_n.view(self.num_layers, 1, batch_size, self.rnn_cell_hidden)
            x = x[-1, 0, : , : ]

        x = x.view(batch_size, 1, -1)           # shape: [batch_size, 1, 2 or 1 * rnn_cell_hidden]
        x = self.rnn_dropout(x)

        x = self.fc(x)
        x = x.view(-1, self.num_class)          # shape: [batch_size, num_class]

        return x
```

Parameters of this model:

- vocab size: 4805
- number of classes: 27
- embedding dimension: 300
- embedding dropoutrate: 0.5
- rnn cell type: LSTM
- rnn cell hidden size: 1000
- bidirectional rnn: False
- number of lstm layers: 1
- dropout rate at last lstm layer hidden: 0.5
- padded sequence length: 64

The Optim:

```
criterion = nn.CrossEntropyLoss().to(device)
optimizer = optim.Adam(model.parameters(), lr=args.lr, weight_decay=1e-6)
```

learning rate here is `0.001`, batch size is `32`.

The tensorboard graph:

[image]

[image]

It seems that this model starts learning after epoch 15. Is it normal?